# jQuery pagination plugin doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have a long list of items on my page

```
<div class="content">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <h4 class="content-title">Clients</h4>

          <div class="clients_wrapper">
            <div class="img-indent3">
                <img src="../Images/US Department of Defense.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="extra-wrap">
                <span class="text-3">US Department of Defense</span>  
                <br>
                text
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clients_wrapper">
            <div class="img-indent3">
                <img src="../Images/Intel Corporation.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="extra-wrap">
                <span class="text-3">IntelCorporation</span>
                <br>
                text.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clients_wrapper">
            <div class="img-indent3">
                <img src="../Images/HSBC Holdings.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="extra-wrap">
                <span class="text-3">HSBC Holdings plc</span>
                <br>
                text.
            </div>
        </div>
```

and I'd like to use jQuery pagination plugin to select my list on pages [link](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/#page-1)

I added in my project script ans css files and added this code on my page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".clients_wrapper").pagination({
            items: 30,
            itemsOnPage: 8,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme'
        });
    });
</script>
```

but as result I got this
[image]

what's wrong in my code?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never heard of this plugin before, but it seems to me that the plugin only creates a specified number of page links for you, but it does not automatically show and/or hide content of your site. Is it the first time you use this plugin? To me, it looks like your selector `.clients_wrapper` is found X times, so X pagination bars are generated by the plugin. I think the plugin works, but it does not do what you expected it to do.

Comment: It looks like you are right, unfortunately :( Can you advise me a plugin to use?

Comment: Actually, I would recommend developing a pagination server-side, because then only the code of the requested page will be delivered to the client. However, if you want to do it with JavaScript, you might want to play with tabs (e.g. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) or an accordion (e.g. http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). Both do what you want: You have multiple elements of which only one shall be visible, and the other ones can be opened via links. (Please accept my previous post if it answers your question.)

Comment: Thank u, I will try to use jqueryui.com/tabs.